# Is there any word for "conversation with myself"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I found one word soliloquy but its meaning lies in "act of speaking", where I want the meaning to be more general like just talking to your self, whether loud or silent. Also *soliloquy* is drama jargon, I want a common generic word.

Comment: Not one word, but this is usually referred to as an *internal monologue*

Comment: [I will not tell you, etc] my thoughts.

Comment: soliloquy is most definitely a drama/play jargon so I don't recommend it. How's "brainstorming" or "bouncing ideas" or "deliberate with myself"

Comment: An 'aside' could also be relavent, but that too is more about drama

Comment: It's called *talking to yourself*.

Comment: Monologue is a lengthy dialogue so inner monologue would only apply to more lengthy inner conversations.

Answer (score 2):

"Reflect", "ruminate", "ponder", "deliberate" all refer to a thoughtful conversation with yourself.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out loud.

Talking yourself through (something).

Thinking things through.

Dialogue with (your)self.

Comment: Also "self-talk" is very good, e.g. "positive self-talk."

Answer (score 0):

Soliloquy is your ‘more general like just talking to yourself, whether loud or silent’ Both are quite distinct from a definition that might start with ‘act of speaking…’ but continues as ‘an act of speaking one's thoughts aloud when by oneself or regardless of any hearers…’

The clue is the ‘sol’ from late Latin soliloquium, from Latin solus ‘alone’ + loqui ‘speak’.  even ‘a part of a play involving a soliloquy.’

That it often refers to 'a part of a play involving a soliloquy'  or even  even ‘a part of a play involving a soliloquy’ doesn't make it drama jargon… ask for instance https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=soliloquy&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&oq=soliloquy&aqs=chrome..69i57.1158j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I rather like the word "musing".

Comment: Could you please explain why?  That would make a much better answer.

Comment: The question was "Is there any word for “conversation with myself”? Musing is just one of the synonyms. Whether it is the best is a matter of opinion. "Soliloquy" is the only one suggested that really fits the definition since it means actually talking i.e. voicing your thoughts as opposed to thinking. I would not refer to that word as "jargon".

Answer (score -2):

There's a polish word for it, i think it's juskah or something like that, (sorry I've only ever heard it be said, not seen it written down,) but basically it stands for "the hypothetical conversation that you convusively play out in your head" I really hope you read this and it's not too late to let you know

Comment: But the questioner wanted a common word, and presumably in *English*...?

Answer (score -3):

Jouska refers to a hypothetical conversation you would compulsively play out in your head. Albeit there is probably more meaning to it, you should look it up and see if it fits what you are searching for.

Comment: Please do not mislead visitors, and more importantly the OP, by suggesting that this word is recognized and used in the English language. It is not. It is a neologism, a word that has not (yet) caught on, created by a somewhat  imaginative poet http://www.dictionaryofobscuresorrows.com/post/24567910939/jouska

Comment: Also, you should not exhort others to "look it up". You should do that and present that corroboration in your answer. **And** you should not simply repeat an answer which has already been given, especially since that says the word is not in fact English.